# What is the fastest way to compile Scala files using maven?

Tags: scala, maven

ideally using the FSC compiler

Question becomes what command or pom file set up should I use?

I'm currently using the scala maven plugin but it doesn't seem to actually use fsc

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run the fsc as part of the compile phase of maven by adding the following to the plugins section of your pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.1</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>cc</id>
   <goals>
     <goal>cc</goal>
   </goals>
   <phase>compile</phase>
   <configuration>
    <useFsc>true</useFsc>
    <once>true</once>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Of course you have to remove the standard scala compile execution from your POM if necessary.