# Maven improperly starting fsc?

Tags: scala, maven, fsc, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to use fsc (fast scala compiler) with my maven project. My `pom.xml` has:

```
...
 <execution>
   <id>cc</id>
   <goals>
     <goal>cc</goal>
   </goals>
   <phase>compile</phase>
   <configuration>
     <useFsc>true</useFsc>
     <once>true</once>
   </configuration>
 </execution>
...
```

as discussed in [What is the fastest way to compile Scala files using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130217)

When I type `mvn scala:cc`, it hangs on:

```
[INFO] wait for files to compile...
```

Running `mvn scala:cc -DdisplayCmd=true -Dverbose=true`

```
 [INFO] cmd:  /bin/sh -c .../java -classpath [redacted] scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer >MainGenericRunner.out 2>MainGenericRunner.err
```

Which seems odd (shouldn't it not include `scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner`?) I noticed that `MainGenericRunner.out` contains

```
no such file: scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer
```

which seems to confirm my suspicion.

Has anyone encountered this, or have a work around? I'd really like to use fsc to speed up my builds. I found one user with a similar output on google groups, but no follow ups.

Running scala 2.8.1 and maven 3.0.3 on OSX

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `mvn scala:cc` maven will use execution id default-cli (or something similar) which is not configured in your pom. Because of that maven will be using defaults of cc goal. Currently your pom is configured to execute cc goal with your customizations during "compile" phase. So, running something like `mvn compile` or `mvn install` should be working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the same behavior occurs when running `mvn compile` and `mvn install`.